# Search string, print line after string is found with further formatting perl

Tags: apache, perl, scalar

I am currently trying to write a script that determines what is wrong with a website on the server. I am stuck on a variable I am trying to create

```
my documentroot =
```

The document root appears in the apache configuration file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 184.171.253.172:80>
    ServerName lernperl.com
    ServerAlias www.lernperl.com
    DocumentRoot /home/lernperl/public_html
```

So, basically I decided to use my domain variable $host which will be the domain and search for `www.$domain.com`, however it is the next line that is important to me. Ideally, I want `/home/lernperl/public_html` put into a scalar. It seems easy but I have been looking so long for an answer. I appreciate any help! I didn't get very far.

```
open (configuration_file, "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf");
my @list1 = <configuration_file>;close configuration_file;
```

Comment: So you've loaded the entire configuration file into `@list1`... now you have to look for the `DocumentRoot` line.  What have you tried so far?  What doesn't work?

Comment: After some lengthy Googling I was able to make a print work.
    
`use strict;
    use warnings;

    @ARGV = </etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf>;
    while ( <> ) {
        print scalar <> if /www.lernperl1.com/;
    }`
This however wont work for me, as I need this in a variable. I am very new to Perl in general and converting this code into a variable turned out to be a difficult task.

Comment: Are you trying to store something in a variable? If so, you can set a scalar variable like so: `my $variable = "/home/lernperl/public_html";` (or whatever you want it to be).

Comment: If you are a perl noob, the best thing is to read a few tutorials so you can work out the basics. There are lots of tutorials online--have a look at http://www.perl.org/learn.html for some you can work through.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what you are trying to do is to use a regular expression to capture the text that follows "DocumentRoot". To set the contents of a variable using the results of a regular expression, you can do the following:

```
if ($line =~ /DocumentRoot (.*?)$/) {
    my $variable = $1;
}
```

More information on perl regular expressions in [perl regular expressions tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Apache config files may contain more than one DocumentRoot and ServerName so your script will need to handle this situation.

Good luck.

Comment: It looks like the OP is trying to read part of an Apache config file into a variable; you're just showing them how to hard-code the path.

Comment: TBH if the OP doesn't know how to set a variable, they need to read some introductory perl documentation before they go any further.

Comment: I would agree that the OP needs to read a tutorial, but they obviously *do* know how to assign to variables, since they included this snippet in their question: `my @list1= <configuration_file>;` What they're having trouble with, it seems, is finding the matching line in the array.

Comment: Suit is correct. I know all about hashs, scalars, and arrays. I am trying to put /home/lernperl/public_html into a scalar by reading the file, grepping for ServerAlias www.lernperl.com, going to the line below it, and awk '{print $2}'. At this point I'm probably just going to use backticks and do it in bash.

Comment: OK, in that case you need http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html - perl regular expressions tutorial. It would also have helped if you had specified the question a little more clearly.

Comment: Edited the answer to add the regex you need. You can go search directly for DocumentRoot, rather than looking for the line after ServerAlias.